# Reference and use Angular 5+ components within Asp.net MVC 3 project

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-3

We have an existing asp.net MVC3 application (old-app). I am creating a new SPA in Angular 5+ (new-app), which will eventually replace the old MVC3 app. However, there will be a transition period and during this time we would like to be able to use some of the new-app components in the old-app.
Some of the preferences:
1) I'd like the new-app to be a separate project
2) I'd prefer the new to be a typescript project rather than an mvc site.

What is the best way to reference or reused components from the new-app into the old-app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Angular Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements) to embed Angular components inside your *old-app* pages, but it does require some extra effort.

You can also use the Angular CLI to generate a library project that contain the shared components between the *old-app* elements and *new-app* project.

It is difficult to predict what challenges you might have without more information. I would experiment early with Angular Elements to see if you can get it to work with your *old-app*.

Angular Elements is still on the edge for browser support. As the Angular Elements as actually part of the browser specification, and last I read the Edge browser was not fully supported.